# How to find the element of a toast message in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, toast

I am trying to get the field address of a toast message but gets disappearing very fast. Is there a way to pause it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a trick that I use:

1. Prepare for the toast notification to appear
2. Open Chrome's Developer Tools
3. Navigate to the Sources tab
4. (Switch back to the site) trigger the toast notification
5. (Switch back to the Sources tab) click "Pause script execution"

[image: screen snippet of the pause script execution button]

The site should now be frozen, including the toast notification.

Try using the "element inspector" or navigate to the Elements tab and search (ctrl+f / cmd+f) for content found in the toast notification's message.